# Using switches to add blocks of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's what I am trying to do in (jquery,html):

The aim is to make it so that when I hit the switch (basic/advanced) a block of html is added to the existing html. Within this new block there will be another switch (less/more) which should added another block.

However I can't seem to (less/more) switch to work. In fact the function is not running at all.

The function that corresponds to the (basic/advanced) switch is:

```
var selectInvestment = "basic";
function expandInvestment(){
    $("input[type=radio][name=expandInformation]").click(function(){
        selectInvestment = $(this).val();
       var huge = 'huge block of html code in here';
        if(selectInvestment == "advanced"){
            $('.investmentBlock').empty();
            $('.investmentBlock').append(huge);
            expandedExpenses();
        } else if(selectInvestment == "basic"){
            $('.investmentBlock').replaceWith("<...more html code...>");
        }
    });
}
```

And it's similar for the less/more switch.

Here is jsfiddle preview. http://jsfiddle.net/1g6uraht/1/

Comment: see the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: repaymentSelection is not defined`, fi it

Comment: fwiw, you can tidy up your code by storing the blocks of html in a `<script type="text/template" id="foo">` tags. Then you can get the text with `$('#foo').html()`

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're dynamically adding your new radio buttons, you'll need to use `on`

```
$("input[type=radio][name=expandedExpenses]").click(function(){
```

becomes

```
$("document").on('click', 'input[type=radio][name=expandedExpenses]', function(){
```

see [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I gave it a try, doesn't seem to work still. http://jsfiddle.net/sL9m65rw/

Comment: Nevermind, made a typo. Thanks a bunch!!